# How to detect result from authorization dialog Core Motion?

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion, combine

I'm working on an app that utilizes Core Motion. During the initial onboarding of the app, it asks the user for permission, and we basically want to update the UI based on the response of that popup (Allowed/Denied). Where for notifications and location services this seems easy to do, it doesn't like a request permission API exists for Core Motion, instead it just triggers the popup when starting updating on a manager like we do now:

```
let motionManager = CMMotionActivityManager()
motionManager.startActivityUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Ideally I want to be able to detect a change in CMMotionActivityManager.authorizationStatus(), but so far haven't been able to come up with a working solution other than implement a timer that checks this property, which I don't feel is a particularly nice solution.

I tried making either authorizationStatus() or the manager as a whole an observable using Combine but that doesn't seem to trigger any updates.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has denied permission, she cannot then grant permission without going to the Settings app. So you don't need to check on a timer. It should suffice to check at app launch and on notifications `applicationWillEnterForeground` and `didBecomeActiveNotification`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I'm trying to determine authorization in response to the user interacting with the system permission dialog, similar to how with push notifications you'd be able to do so like this

`requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { granted, _ in }`